# Sending messages to people im not friends with on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-friends

so I am not the person who has this problem, rather their daughter. My mom was using Facebook and tried to message someone without sending a friend request, I beleive it was an old childhood friend, anyways, a screen popped up saying "log in to messenger"... it shows one account, her main account, the other account (not shown) is her business page, anyways, so she clicked her profile and it did nothing. She cannot message ANYONE other than her Facebook friends.... please help!!!!!!